# Simplest way to create a wrapper class around some strings for a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wrapper

I'm building a simple hex editor in C#, and I've decided to use each cell in a DataGrid to display a byte*. I know that DataGrid will take a list and display each object in the list as a row, and each of that object's properties as columns. I want to display rows of 16 bytes each, which will require a wrapper with 16 string properties. While doable, it's not the most elegant solution. Is there an easier way? I've already tried creating a wrapper around a public string array of size 16, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

*The rationale for this is that I can have spaces between each byte without having to strip them all out when I want to save my edited file. Also it seems like it'll be easier to label the rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider creating a regular Grid with 16 columns in `ColumnDefinitions` and dynamic `RowDefinitions` collections and placing a borderless `TextBox` in each cell. You'd need to overload some key-handling to make it easier for user to navigate between text boxen, but the similar thing would be necessary for DataGrid's cells.

If you still want to use DataGrid, pointing `ItemsSource` to a list of 16-sized arrays should work. Create 16 `DataGridTextColumns` from code. Each one with `Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", i))`, where `i` is 0..15. Indexing property is just another property and you can easily bind to it. These don't have to be string arrays: use bytes and create a IValueConverter between hex string and byte. Oh, and turn off `AutoGenerateColumns`.

Comment: The regular grid sounds easiest to implement. I had actually thought of doing something similar when I noticed the DataGrid control and thought it would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use MultiBinding.

```
     <my:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding HexDataArray}">
        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
            <my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                          <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} ...">
                              <Binding Path="Array[0]" />
                              <Binding Path="Array[1]" />
                                .........................
                            </MultiBinding>
                          </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </my:DataGrid.Columns>
    </my:DataGrid>
```